# Checking travelmodes between google maps places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any way of knowing what Travel Modes are available for directions between two places in Google Maps v3?

Of course, requesting directions for each travel mode and checking which ones return ZERO_RESULTS is a possibility, but it implies four http requests and four google api requests, which I'd very much like to avoid.

Ultimately I would like the user to select a travel mode prior to running the directions service, but they should know if that travel mode is actually available prior to selected.

Comment: As far as I know there is no straightforward way to get this information via one API call. Why don't you create a feature request on [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:DirectionsAPI%20type:Enhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars)

Comment: Thanks. I'll stick with the four calls for now until theres ever a feature for that.